# Kotlin Retrofit Rx android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, kotlin

In my activity there are one search EditText and RecylerView which load data from server. When start typing on search, real time search will call to api. Now I got android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error.
Do you have any idea about this?

```
disposable = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchEditText)
            .skipInitialValue()
            .flatMap {
                apiService.getContactList("", it.text().toString())
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                {
                    adapter?.addItem(it)
                }, { error ->
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to call apiService.getContactList in Main thread (you can see it if you will put breakpoint in this line and call Thread.currentThread() in Watcher). Move subscribeOn upper in the chain.

```
disposable = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchEditText)
        .skipInitialValue()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap {
            apiService.getContactList("", it.text().toString())
        }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
                   adapter?.addItem(it)
                }, { error ->
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        )
```

Comment: even if your answer is correct and accepted, remember to add an explanation. simply giving code doesn't really help teach anyone much